# Pass arguments include new line character(\n) into C program from command line

Tags: c, command-line, newline

I want to pass a shell code(string) in linux, include new line character as arguments into C program from command line, example : `./myprogram "number=0  \n while [ $number -lt 10 ]; do \n echo $number \n  number=$((number + 1)) \n done`"

if I put this string directly in C code, and use system(command_string), the symbol '\n' is interpreted as newline character and it'll work well. But if I send this string through command line as above it'll not work. the symbol '\n' is not interpreted as newline character. How can I sovle this problem?

Comment: Use \\n instead of a simple \n.

Comment: Couldn't you just hit the return key instead of entering `\n`?

Comment: I tried \\n, it also did'nt work, when I printf this string, it displays \n instead of new line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by  squeamish ossifrage's comment, provided that you are using an Unix-like shell (meaning not cmd.exe on Windows ...), a raw newline in a quoted string is interpreted as itself and does not terminate the command.

You should write simply :

```
./myprogram "number=0
 while [ \$number -lt 10 ]; do 
 echo \$number  number=\$((number + 1)) 
 done"
```

Beware : no `\` before the newline. If you put one, the newline will be taken as a continuation and will be removed.

Edit : but of course `$` characters have to be escaped between `"`...

Comment: it doesn't work, symbol '$' also is interpreted wrong

Comment: So there's no way to pass `\n` newline escapes into a single line for a command line argument?

Answer (score 0):

\n is included as part of double quotes. Can you try this :

./myprogram "number=0" \n "while [ $number -lt 10 ]; do" \n "echo $number" \n "number=$((number + 1))" \n "done"

Comment: It still doesn't work, if I try this, \n will be interpreted as n